# Parallel.foreach in initializing conversation manager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I'm using mvc2 and nhibernate 2.1.2

In my controller class I'm calling `foreachParty` method like this:

```
OrganizationStructureService.ForEachParty<Department>(department, null, p =>
{
    p.AddParentWithoutRemovingExistentAccountability(domainDepartment, AccountabilityTypeDbId.SupervisionDepartmentOfDepartment);
}
    }, x => (!(x.AccountabilityType.Id == (int)AccountabilityTypeDbId.SupervisionDepartmentOfDepartment)));


static public void ForEachParty<T>(Party party, 
                                   PartyTypeDbId? partyType, 
                                   Action<Party> action, 
                                   Expression<Func<Accountability, bool>> expression = null)
                                   where T : Party
{
    IList<Party> chilrden = new List<Party>();
    IList<Accountability> acc = party.Children;

    if (party != null)
        action(party);

    if (partyType != null)
        acc = acc.Where(p => p.Child.PartyTypes.Any(c => c.Id == (int)partyType)).ToList();

    if (expression != null)
        acc = acc.AsQueryable().Where(expression).ToList();

    Parallel.ForEach(acc, p =>
    {
        if (partyType == null)
            ForEachParty<T>(p.Child, null, action);
        else
            ForEachParty<T>(p.Child, partyType, action);
    });
}
```

But just after executing the action on `foreach.parallel`, I don't know why the conversation is getting closed and I see

> current conversation is not initilized yet or its closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe NHiberante session is not threadsafe, so you cannot query the database parallel without creating new sessions for each thread.

Comment: does it mean that i cant use parallel in such cases or i have another option to use it?

Comment: That means you can use it when you do not use a session, or create the session inside the loop.